# How does the appsecret_proof provide better security?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

The Graph API offers something called an `appsecret_proof` but how is it any less compromisable than the access token? It's the HMAC of the access token and the secret, so it's going to be the same for each API call anyway. Since both the `appsecret_proof` and the access code are needed for each API call, they could be sniffed together. So how does it make things more secure? What is the rationale?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let´s say someone hacks your App and gets an Access Token of another User. Without `appsecret_proof`, he would be able to use the Access Token for something malicious. With `appsecret_proof`, the Access Token alone is useless for anyone who gets it. You can only use the Access Token with the generated `appsecret_proof`, so you would need the App Secret too - and the App Secret should only be used on the server anyway. It´s called "Secret" for a reason :)

More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests

Example: Extended Page Tokens are valid forever, so they usually get stored in a database. If some user gets access to one of those, he may be able to publish stuff to the Page wall (if the Token includes `publish_actions`). `appsecret_proof` makes sure you can only use the Page Token on your server with the App Secret. So the hacker would have to get the Page Token AND he would need to somehow get your App Secret too.

Comment: But what apps stores the access token of another user? Isn't the whole approach to protect the app's own access token from being stolen? If that's the case, then if some hacks the app and steals it, the `appsecret_proof` could be stolen just as easily too.

Comment: if your app secret gets stolen, you would have a lot more problems ;) - the approach is to protect EVERY access token. but not from being stolen, but from being used outside your app.

Comment: access tokens can be stored to do stuff when the user is not online - extended page tokens are valid forever, it does make a lot of sense to store them.